# Why is the sentence " There is (62) days left until we have to take the exam." correct?

Tags: grammar

Why is the sentence " There is (62) days left until we have to take the exam." correct? It must be like "There are (62) days left until we have to take the exam."?

Comment: It ain't correct.

Comment: What is the role of the parentheses in the example?

Comment: Because it's got unnecessary parentheses in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten miles is too far to walk.(Ten miles refers to singular distance).
100 dollars is too much to pay.(100 dollars refers to singular amount/price).
Five years is too long for that offense.(Five years refers to singular time or duration).
There are (62) days left until we have to take the exam.(Is correct as it refers to plural 62 days)

Answer (score 3):

The grammatically sound sentence should be:

> There are 62 days left.

However, the simplified version ***There is*** (most commonly, if not exclusively in its contracted form ***There's***) seems to be gaining increasing popularity, possibly under the influence of non-native speakers of English.

Francophones, too, have no plural construction for this: "il y a" means both *there is* and *there are*.

Part of this trend among Anglophones seems to be corresponding with the [theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_reform) that languages become more simplified over time, as people break the established patterns.

Also, part of the confusion could be because when distances, periods of time, sums of money, etc. are used as subjects, they're considered as units and hence get singular verbs:

> Ten miles is too far to walk.
>
> 100 dollars is too much to pay.
>
> Five years is too long for that offense.

Comment: This question came from [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522122/it-is-62-days-left-to-take-sit-for-the-matriculation-exam#comment1269998_522122) where I said, “There’s 62 days left...”.  OP changed that to the uncontracted form to arrive at his question.

Comment: Yeah, "There's 62 days left" is idiomatic (if not strictly "proper").   I suspect this is because it "flows" better than "There're 62 days left". "There is 62 days left" is just wrong, however.